# can't create virtualenv on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Docker file with the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y python3.8
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3.8-venv python3.8-dev
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/run/env
RUN python3.8 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

I get this error when building it:

```
Step 8/8 : RUN python3.8 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
---> Running in d05326069de2
Error: Command '['/run/env/bin/python3.8', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' 
returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

When I try to add this line before it:

```
RUN python3.8 -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

I get the error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 466, in _init_posix
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata__x86_64-linux-gnu'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 41):

As workaround

```
sudo ln -s   /usr/lib/python3.8/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py  /usr/lib/python3.8/_sysconfigdata__x86_64-linux-gnu.py
```

But i hope it will be fixed soon in Ubuntu.

Comment: Wow. This worked, but is there a bug report I can follow that documents the issue?

Comment: Can confirm this fixed a similar issue for me on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: I get the following error: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/python3.8/_sysconfigdata__x86_64-linux-gnu.py': File exists` And the problem persists.

Comment: I encounter this issue in Ubuntu 20.04 trying to install python3.9 from ppa. solution is working. you could use a hard link, though.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1, Python3.9: solution works like a charm!

Comment: In my case I was trying to install Ansible on 20.04 when I encountered the problem.  The link fixed it.

Comment: This link also fixed python 3.8.9 which I upgraded from 16.04 via 18.04 using `do-release-upgrade`, I don't recall using the deadsnakes PPA at all.

Comment: For Python3.9: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3.9/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py  /usr/lib/python3.9/_sysconfigdata__x86_64-linux-gnu.py` worked like a charm on Ubuntu 18.04 as well

Answer (score 6):

For me, I could fix my Python 3.8 installation and the problem with this:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: This comment deserves more upvotes. It fixed the issue for me and seems to not cut corners.

Answer (score 4):

oops, this was a mistake in the packaging -- I've gone ahead and fixed it [here](https://github.com/deadsnakes/python3.9/commit/f1fee14a80a61defd9dfb62d53fce7023f6d08d8)

there was a subtle conflict between the system `python3-distuils` (provided by debian) and the `python3.x-venv` module (provided by the ppa)

---

disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of deadsnakes

Answer (score 0):

This is really embarrassing but for me, the issue was my computer didn't have the required version by the Pipfile so I used `pipenv install --python 3.8` in which 3.8 was a version I did have instead of 3.9 like the Pipfile required.